# Using smarty {include} within jquery .append

Tags: javascript, jquery, smarty

These both work, I'm not having a problem with the append function reading HTML or smarty:

```
$("div").append("<h3>Area Name</h3>");
$("div").append("{$area->c['name']|e}");
```

but I can't get a smarty `{include}` to work. Example:

```
$('div').append("{include file='login/area/names.tpl}");
```

I've tried using `.after()` instead of `.append()` and variations of using `{literal}` and/or `{ldelim}{rdelim}`. Any thoughts?

Comment: didn't you forget to close `'login/area/names.tpl` with a single-quote?

Comment: Sorry, but is this event possible? What if the template you are trying to include, has not been compiled yet?

Comment: Can you explain the actual problem you're seeing please - "it doesn't work" could mean anything from crashing the server to the text not looking right on the page...

Comment: @DavidDomain Smarty doesn't know or care about the JS, it just renders a bunch of text to send to the browser, which then happens to be executing that text as a script. When it sees the include, it includes that template (and compiles it, if necessary).

Comment: By the way: it isn't the `append` method that reads smarty, it's the PHP Smarty library that replaces those tags before the response goes to the browser.

Comment: (disclaimer: i'm unfamiliar with smarty) Javascript is rather picky about whitespace in strings - it doesn't allow newlines.  I can't find the 'smarty' way to do `s/\n/\\n/g` quickly though..